# What is my brothers' name

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

Yeah, so, I'm not sure if this'll work or not as I'm trying something new and I'm still learning how to make functional puzzles.

Anyway, this puzzle reminded me of my brothers' name. Can you guess what it is?

> I don't *think* I've made any mistakes,

**HINT1**

> The name is a comon one

**HINT 2**

> This puzzle kind of just... *feels* wrong in so many levels... yet no mistaks have been made?!

**HINT 3**

> A 6 letter word that could be used to describe this puzzle.

**HINT 4**

> My bro got me a laptop the other day. It's got so mny problems with it that you cant even use it; It just doesn't work!

Comment: brothers' (more than one brother) or brother's (one brother)?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot13(Vagrerfgvat bofreingvba)

Comment: why is it a comma at the end of the spoiler?

Comment: This is really confusing mainly because there are several mistakes in the problem, and it's unclear whether those relate at all to "I don't think I've made any mistakes." Like the misspelling of mistakes in hint 2, or the stray comma in hint 1, or the use of brothers' instead of brother's.

Comment: If anyone has any comments on how I could have improved this puzzle I'd be greatly appreciative. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is your brother's name is

> Ken

Because this puzzle is:

> **Bro Ken** - the errant apostrophe in the title, comma ending of the original mistakes, misspellings of comon, mistaks and mny, and no apostrophe in cant.

Comment: Wow.. I was close. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a start on it:

> Your brother has a name that means mistake or error, like many things in this enigmatic puzzle. I was thinking an anagram of mistake like Kamiste.

A list of the mistakes I've found

> The apostrophe (in the title and puzzle), the comma, the m in comon, the space missing between hint and 1, the missing e in mistaks, and not sure if this is one but the hyphen missing in hint 3 and it is phrased weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Singular

Just a wild guess, based on:

> I don't think I made any mistakes.
>  Which you did—namely, you used the plural brothers' when I think you meant to use the singular brother's.

Comment: Interesting, but no cigar. I've added some hints above to hopefully point something out =)