# My coworker's apparantly hard to buy for

Tags: word, pattern

I'm looking for a four-letter answer to the following puzzle:

> My coworker's apparantly hard to buy for.
> A calender might make a good gift.
> It's a consciencious man I'm dealing with.
> He's indispensible in the work he does.

Comment: Bitten once again by the similarity of the Puzzling and Workplace icons in the HNQ – was wondering how a coworker being hard to buy gifts for was a workplace problem!

Comment: rot13(Gung glcb va gur gvgyr ernyyl, ernyyl, vexf zr... V nz tynq V ernq gur fbyhgvba orsber cebcbfvat na rqvg gubhtu!)

Comment: @MatthieuM. rot13(V unq gb onggyr zl BPQ ba guvf bar...)

Comment: Here's predicting you're going to have to do a lot of rolling back of well-meaning edits on this one.

Comment: @Randal'Thor They can edit my posts but they'll never take my commentz!

Comment: Related: [What is my brothers' name (Wordplay)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84595/5373)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are a

> **TIPO** (*TYPO*)

> Every line has a word which is misspelled.
>  appar**e**ntly - apparantly
>  calend**e**r - calendar
>  conscien**c**ious -conscientious
>  indispens**i**ble - indispensable

Thanks to @M Oehm

> If we take the indexes of the incorrect letters and take related A..Z values, we get T, I, P, O which is again a misspelled **TYPO** which fits the pattern. Since, there's no riddle tag, this is all we need to look for.

Comment: Good observation. If you rot13(gnxr gur glcbf' cbfvgvbaf nf N-M vaqrk, lbh rira trg n gurzngvp zvffcryyvat bs n gurzngvp jbeq). That would give an answer to bobble's comment above, but it doesn't explain the riddle itself.

Comment: @MOehm Ah. Yep. Thanks. That makes more sense. Will add it in.

Comment: @rybo111 Sure. If there's also a riddle, you can add it. I've tried to explain it. But I could be far off lol.

Comment: @rybo111 Done that.